# WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis

Hi I am using Laravel with Redis .When I am trying to access a key by get method then get following error "WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value"

I am using following code to access the key value -

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    //$redis = app()->make("redis");
    $redis = Redis::connection();

    return $redis->get("doctor:8a772886-e7b2-442a-a0d5-621307510c6a");

});
```

Comment: go to redis cli and type: TYPE doctor

Comment: Did you try using the Redis facade directly? So instead of using a Redis instance, try calling the `get` method statically: `Redis::get("doctor:8a772886-e7b2-442a-a0d5-621307510c6a")`

Comment: @noodles_ftw when this error pops up it means that he is using wrong action to the following type Redis:: is just another facade to $redis->

Comment: its giving the same error Redis::get("doctor:8a772886-e7b2-442a-a0d5-621307510c6a").

Comment: @яша Ah I see. Not too familiar with the Redis CLI but I thought it might be related. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: TYPE doctor  is giving output hash

Comment: Try the solution I have written to you

Comment: Try LRANGE for this type of keys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could you please try this code sample and see if it works for you.

```
return $redis->HGETALL("doctor:8a772886-e7b2-442a-a0d5-621307510c6a");
```